# $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_j$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[a x_j+b y_j]$ also converges absolutely.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that if $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_j$ are absolutely convergent series, then for $a$, $b$ real numbers, then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}[a x_j+b y_j]$ is also absolutely convergent.

We know that $x_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j| \to x$ and $y_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}|y_j| \to y$ as $n \to \infty$.

We need to prove that $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a x_j+b y_j|$ converges.

$s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a x_j+b y_j| \le \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a| |x_j|+\sum_{j=1}^{n} |b| |y_j|=|a| x_n + |b| y_n$

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You're done here. $s_n$ is an increasing sequence so it suffices to show that it's bounded from above to conclude that it converges. $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded since they converges so $s_n$ is bounded too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did : $$|s_n| \leq |a||x_n| + |b||y_n| \leq |a|S+|b|T=K, \forall n \geq 1 \to \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} |s_n| \leq K \to |s_n| \text{ converges} \to \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j \text{ converges absolutely.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $|ax_j + by_j| \le |a||x_j| + |b||y_j|$ for all $j$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty (|a| |x_j| + |b||y_j|)$ converges (being the sum of two convergent series $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty |a||x_j|$ and $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty |b||y_j|$), by direct comparison the series $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty |ax_j + by_j|$ converges.